# How can I handle a JSON streaming GET request using RxJs

Tags: javascript, json, typescript, rxjs, jsonstream

I have an API endpoint that streams a JSON response.
Now I want to use RxJs observables to stream the data chunks like this:

[image]

And suscribe to the observable in other classes. How can i do it? thanks!

I consume it in this way:

```
http.get({
        hostname: 
        port: 80,
        path: '/api/' + "v4" + '/contests/' + "contest" + '/event-feed',
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        qs: {
            strict: false,
            stream: true
        }
    }, (res) => {
        res.on('data', (chunk) => {
            rawData += chunk;
            let obj;
            try {
                obj = JSON.parse(chunk);
                console.log(obj)
            } catch (e) {
                if (e.constructor.name != "SyntaxError") console.log("[ERROR]: " + e);
                else console.log("...");
            }

        });
        res.on('end', () => {
            try {
                console.log("---FIN---\n");
                const parsedData = JSON.parse(rawData);
                console.log(parsedData);
            } catch (e) {
                console.error(e.message);
            }
        });
```

And it works.

Comment: What is http? is the HttpClient used in Angular?

Answer (score 0):

There's actually quite a lot of subtlety in what you're asking here and how it interacts with Observables which I'll try to delve into a bit...

One way of doing this is to create a [Subject](https://rxjs.dev/guide/subject) before you trigger the `http.get` which you then call the `.next()` method on when you receive data. You return the `Subject` and then subscribe to that. The challenge here is that the http operation may have already completed by the time you subscribe and you miss the data chunks.

A way to avoid missing stuff is to use [ReplaySubject](https://rxjs.dev/guide/subject#replaysubject) instead which will buffer and replay some values to new subscribers.

The more usual way to do it is to not actually trigger the http call *until* someone subscribes which you can do like this...

```js
var http = require('https');
var { Observable } = require('rxjs');

function prepareConnection() {
    return new Observable(subscriber => {
        http.get({
            hostname: 
            port: 80,
            path: '/api/' + "v4" + '/contests/' + "contest" + '/event-feed',
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            qs: {
                strict: false,
                stream: true
           }
        }, (res) => {
            res.on('data', (chunk) => {
                let obj;
                try {
                    obj = JSON.parse(chunk);
                    subscriber.next(obj);
                } catch (e) {
                    subscriber.error(e);
                }        
            });
            res.on('end', () => {
                subscriber.complete();
            });
        });
    });
}

prepareConnection().subscribe({
    next(x) { console.log(x); },
    error(err) { console.error('something wrong occurred: ' + err); },
    complete() { console.log('done'); }
});
```

The function passed to the constructor executes when someone subscribes to the [Observable](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/class/Observable) with the subscriber being the first argument of that function that you can call `next()` etc on.

The caveat here being that each new subscriber will trigger an new http call. That may or may not be the behaviour you want - If it's not what you want you can use [share](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/share) to share one subscription e.g.

```
let connection = prepareConnection().pipe(share());

connection.subscribe({
   ...
});

connection.subscribe({
   ...
});
```